find . -type f is including type PIPE on NTFS partition search (GNU find version 4.9.0)
While searching for regular files on a mounted NTFS external drive (using Debian 12, find ver.4.9.0,)
The search is including FIFO pipes stored on the NTFS partition.
find . -type f
and when I tried: tar . -type p, it did not return any results.
I noticed this while creating a hash file of all the files on the partition (using b3sum) ;
and the program kept hanging, every time it tried to read an empty pipe...
(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 b3sum)
Tried mknod pipe1 p on the NTFS partition: find . -type f would find it,
but find . -type p would not find the file.
find is working fine on the ext4 partitions.
find . -type f
Should have only returned a list of regular files
but also returns FIFO pipes stored on the NTFS partition.
